# manipulating textarea value so that a default message is shown under various circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is how it works. At its natural state a message is shown. When the user focus on the textarea the message is gone. If the user focus out of the textarea than the message display.

My problem is that i only want the message to display at start and if and only if there is no user written text in the text field. that is as soon as the user start to type even when he is not focus on the textarea the message does not display and the user text remains. if the user clears out the textarea than the message display when its out of focus.

My problem is making sure that the message does not display after the user has enter some information.

Below is what I have tried.

```
 $(function() {

      // Initiate the textarea placeholder content
      if($(".more").val() != '') {

        var content = "Please provide any feedback from your experience or/and any features you would like to be added or removed.";
      // Empty it's value upon select
      $(".more").val(content);
      }
        $(".more").focus(function(event) {
            // Erase text from inside textarea

            if($(this).val() != '') {
              $(".more").val('');
          }
        });

        // Display the placeholder when the textarea is out of focus. Ensure that its empty.
        $(".more").focusout(function(event) {
          // Erase text from inside textarea
          if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val("Please provide any feedback from your experience or/and any features you would like to be added or removed.");
          }

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this below block, your are clearing the text area if it is not empty, **you shouldn't do that, you have to clear the text area if it matches to some default text.So that the user typed text is not cleared on focus in.**

```
  if($(this).val() != '') {
     $(".more").val('');
```

1.By default, insert some default text.
2.On focus out , if text area is empty the insert default value.
3.On focus in , if text area value is equal to default text , then empty the text area .

Try this .

```js
var DefaultText = "Please provide any feedback from your experience or/and any features you would like to be added or removed."

$('#temp').val(DefaultText);

$('#temp').focusout(function(event) {
  if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(DefaultText); // add default text if there is no text
});

$('#temp').focusin(function(event) {
  if ($(this).val() == DefaultText) // remove text only if it default text
    $(this).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='temp'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter your biography here"></textarea>
```

Comment: the placeholder wasn't working properly in the sense that it was not beingde display

Comment: What do you mean? This works fine in all browsers of the past ~5 years.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: actually _placeholder_ on <textarea>s is relatively new, not 5 years old like it is for <input>...

Comment: [See note 1 here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), only applied to very old Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want the placeholder to vanish when the textarea is focused, which you can use CSS for. i use this a lot at work and it's a nice subtle touch.

```
/* set placeholder to transprent on focused elements:  */
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: transparent; }
:focus::-moz-placeholder { color: transparent; }
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color: transparent; }
```

NOTE: you have to use separate rules to keep the different css parsers happy.

live demo: http://pagedemos.com/nm2c6753g3r8/